# Are there continuous chaotic systems where nearby paths diverge at rates other then exponential?

Tags: chaos-theory

I know that in general, nearby paths in a chaotic system tend to diverge exponentially, but are there continuous systems where paths diverge at other rates? For example, is there a system where nearby paths diverge say double exponentially or at some rate determined by tetration? Or are there ones with slower divergence, for example only quadratic or cubic divergence instead of exponential?

Comment: In turbuelent fluid, tracers typically follow Richardson's scaling law with $|x-y|^2\sim t^3$